# Show large sharepoint List on a DataCard

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

i have a sharepoint list "clients" with 1500 items or more. I have another list "production" and i have a form1 that edit or is connected to production list.

On that form on the datacardvalue3 on the item property i have = Filter(Distinct(val_clientes2; descripcion); StartsWith(Value; DataCardValue3.SearchText)), but its only show the first 500 items or something like that. it doesn't search on the item above 500, i need to search on all the list an that bring me until the last item on that list.

it only seach until the clients with name that begins for the letter P

Excuse me and i really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

I need to search the clients names that begins for the letter w  or  z .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first to see if in SharePoint you have an Index created for `descripcion` column.

Then try updating the expression to the following:

```
Distinct(
  Filter(
    val_clientes2;
    StartsWith(descripcion; DataCardValue3.SearchText)
  );
  descripcion
)
```

Comment: you are so kind mi problem was solved, thanks a lot. God bless you